# Where will I remove permission for inheriting permissions?

Tags: active-directory, storage, file-permissions, user-permissions, end-user

I want to remove certain groups and people from accessing a folder in a shared storage which is hosted on a separate server but I keep getting this error message "You cannot remove *person_name* (*domain_url*) because this object is inheriting permission from its parent."

Answer (score 0):

log into the File server and locate the folder where you want to remove access from people or groups. Open *Properties* and go to the *Security* tab and select *Advance*. In the advance option you can add/remove inheritance.